# Transfer at Munich, do I have to clear immigration and is 40 minutes enough time?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, customs-and-immigration, short-connections, muc

I am visiting Paris from India. The flight is via Munich. There is only a 40 minute gap before departing to Paris from there. So my question is 40 minutes a sufficient time to get the immigration and customs check and still manage to get the Paris flight? Is it possible to do the immigration service check in Paris airport so that I would have sufficient time?

Comment: If the two flights are with the same airline and were bought at the same time, then if you miss the second flight because the connection was too tight they have to put you on another later flight (at their expense).

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: I am an Indian citizen. thanks for the responses. I checked the link that was given on top for answers. Looking at those answers 40 minutes seems to be doable if the flights are on time.

Comment: You've probably figured it out already from the comments, but to be explicit about it, your Munich-Paris flight is an *internal* Schengen flight.  For the purpose of immigration control, it is analogous to a domestic flight.  You will therefore depart Munich from the intra-Schengen part of the airport, and arrive in Paris in the intra-Schengen part of the airport, which is why you will have to clear immigration in Munich.

Answer (score -3):

Munich has an international area, so you should be able to stay there and do the immigration service check in Paris (provided both legs of the flight are on the same ticket).

Comment: I'm afraid that since Munich is the OP's first port of entry into the Schengen area they'll have to go through immigration.

Answer (score -3):

I've been in Munich 4 times, if you have a connecting flight then you don't pass immigration, still the time is very thigh, considering you need to get out of a plane full of people and run to another gate, it may be possible but I would check with the airlines if I were you.

Comment: I'm afraid that since Munich is the OP's first port of entry into the Schengen area they'll have to go through immigration.